# NFA with exponential number of states when determinized

Tags: automata, finite-automata

How can I build an example of a regular language where the minimal DFA has $2^n$ states and the minimal NFA has $n$ states? Obviously the DFA's state-set should contain all subsets of the the NFA's state-set, but I don't know how to start. Any suggestions to put me on the right track?

Comment: Note that the [Wikipedia article on DFA minimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization#cite_note-4) references suitable examples (although you have to figure out the small NFA yourself).

Comment: See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6063/how-to-prove-that-dfas-from-nfas-can-have-exponential-number-of-states which has an explicit construction for a slightly weaker bound.

Answer (score 21):

The standard example is the language $L$ of all words over an alphabet $A$ of size $n$ that *don't* contain all the different letters. There is an NFA accepting $L$ with $n+1$ states (or $n$ states if you allow multiple starting states): first guess a letter $a$ which is missing, then go (with an $\epsilon$-move) to an accepting state with self-loops for all letters other than $A$.

Any DFA for $L$ requires at least $2^n$ states. This can be seen using the Myhill-Nerode theorem. Let $S_1,S_2$ be two different subsets of $A$, and $w(S_1),w(S_2)$ words which contain all and only the letters in $S_1,S_2$, respectively. Without loss of generality, suppose $a \in S_1 \setminus S_2$, and let $w = w(A-a)$. Then $w(S_1)w \notin L$ while $w(S_2)w \in L$.

Answer (score 13):

This is a late answer, but apparently nobody gave the optimal solution.
Take $A = \{a, b\}$, $Q_n = \{0, 1, \ldots, n-1\}$ et ${\cal A}_n =
(Q_n, A, E_n, \{0\}, \{0\})$, with
$$
  E_n = \{(i, a, i+1) \mid 0 \leqslant i \leqslant n-2\} \cup \{(n-1, a, 0)\} \cup 
    \{(i, b, i) \mid 1 \leqslant i \leqslant n-1\} \cup \{(i, b, 0) \mid 1 \leqslant i \leqslant n-1\}
$$
This NFA on a two-letter alphabet has $n$ states, only one initial and one final states and its equivalent minimal DFA has $2^n$ states.

Comment: Very clever! The language accepted by this automaton is $(a^n + aW_{n-1}b)^*$, where $W_{n-1}$ consists of all words containing the letter $a$ at most $n-1$ times.

Comment: @yuval-filmus This example is not mine. I wanted to give a reference, but at the moment I don't remember where I saw it.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek $\{0\}\cdot b = \emptyset$.

Comment: Sorry, you are right; I didn’t notice that $(0,b,0)$ was missing.

Answer (score 11):

this is an exercise in the book "Finite Automata" by Mark V. Lawson
Heriot-Watt University, Edinburgh, page 68:

Let $n \geq 1$. Show that the language $(0+1)^\ast 1(0+1)^{n−1}$ can be recognised by
a non-deterministic automaton with $n+1$ states. Show that any deterministic
automaton that recognises this language must have at least $2^n$ states.
This example shows that an exponential increase in the number of states
in passing from a non-deterministic automaton to a corresponding determin-
istic automaton is sometimes unavoidable.

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to guess that you mean that the *optimal* DFA has $2^n$ states. Maybe this doesn't get you $2^n$ states, but it's $\Omega(2^n)$.

From "Communication Complexity" by Kushilevitz and Nisan in exercise 12.6:

"For some constant [non-negative integer] $c$, consider the (finite) language $L_c = \{ww\mid w \in \{0,1\}^c\}$."

and the book continues on asking you to prove that you can find a co-NFA recognizing $L_c$ that uses $O(c)$ states and also that you cannot do better than $\Omega(2^c)$ states for a DFA.

Comment: Also, the proof of the second part "requires" communication complexity, so this might not be suitable for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What do you mean by co-NFA?

Comment: Basically, switch "accepting" with "rejecting" in the definition of an NFA. That is, if none of the possible paths lead to a rejecting state, you accept, otherwise you reject.

Comment: In fact, the $2^c$ lower bound follows quite easily from Myhill-Nerode. (In fact, you can get something like $(c+1)2^c$.) But my co-NFA uses $\Theta(c^2)$ states.

Comment: Finite languages are somewhat boring in this regard. See also [here](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/4962/1546).