# Maximum number of states in minimized DFA from NFA with $n$ states

Tags: automata, finite-automata, nondeterminism

If an NFA with $n$ states is converted to an equivalent minimized DFA then what will be the maximum number of states in the DFA? Will it be $2^n$ or $2n$?

Comment: Try the canonical NFA for the language $L=\{ w\in \{a,b\}^* | \text{ $n$th character from behind is $a$}\}$. Check the number classes of the Myhill-Nerode relation for $L$, which gives you the number of states of the minimal DFA.

Comment: See this [question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3381/nfa-with-exponential-number-of-states-when-deteminized/16287#16287)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum number of states is $2^n$. Conversion from NFA to DFA is done by [subset construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction) and the number of states of the resulting DFA is in the worst case $2^n$. Minimization of the resulting DFA in the worst case might not reduce the number of states.

An example of this is automaton that accepts strings over $\Sigma = \{0, 1\}$ which have $1$ as the $n$th symbol from the end. Of course, $n$ is a concrete number. A NFA has states $q_0...q_n$ and the following transition function:

$$(q_0, 0) \rightarrow \{q_0\} \;\;\;\; (q_0, 1) \rightarrow \{q_0, q_1 \}$$
$$(q_i, 0) \rightarrow \{q_{i+1}\} \;\;\;\; (q_i, 1) \rightarrow \{q_{i+1}\} \;\;\;  1 \leq i \leq n-1$$

Intuitively, the corresponding DFA needs to remember last $n$ symbols since it does not know has it seen the end, which means there are $2^{n}$ states. For more details, I suggest looking into [this book](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/ialc.html). It has a more detailed proof and generally covers these topics in thorough.