# Given an non-deterministic finite automaton, will its determinization always have unreachable states?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, nondeterminism

Given an **NFA** that accepts the regular language ***L***, will its equivalent **DFA** which accepts the same language ***L*** always have unreachable states.
If it does, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there aren't always unreachable states.  Consider the NFA with one state, $q$, and no transitions.  (It accepts the language $\{\epsilon\}$ if $q$ is accepting, and accepts $\emptyset$, otherwise.)

If you determinize this automaton, you end up with a two-state DFA with a transition from the start state $\{q\}$ to the other state, $\emptyset$, so both states are reachable.

Answer (score 0):

The powerset construction shows that for every NFA with $n$ states there is an equivalent DFA with $2^n$ states. Every example in which this is tight – that is, the minimal DFA has $2^n$ states – is a counterexample to your claim. You can find such an example, for arbitrary $n$ and over a binary alphabet, in [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/16287/683).