# Are there more succint algorithm for translating NFA's to DFA's?

Tags: complexity-theory, finite-automata, nondeterminism

When translating an **NFA** to its deterministic equivalent, we get an exponential  blowup due to the powerset construction method. I tried to search but couldn't find an appropriate question regarding this question:

I was wondering if there are algorithms that are better, even if it's just a tiny bit, for translating **NFA**s to **DFA**s?

Comment: I dont think so. Its pretty well known that this exponential increase is necessary

Comment: See this question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3381/nfa-with-exponential-number-of-states-when-deteminized